# Displaying a file from downloads folder in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am downloading a file from url using a chrome extension and saving it to downloads folder.I want to display the same file again using Chrome extension api, Is this possible?

I am trying to search the file via Chrome downloads but I am not getting any results

```
Chrome.downloads.search({query:'acc.storefinder.js'}, function(results) {
    //This is not returning any results
    alert(results);
});
```

Comment: `Chrome` or `chrome`? What if setting `query`to the empty object?

Comment: It's chrome only..empty means?

Comment: I mean anything outputs if you directly call `chrome.downloads.search({}, function(results) {console.log(results);});`

Comment: It doesn't output anything

Comment: please make sure you have declared the `download` permission in `manifest.json` and view the right console in background page.